# Would appreciate feedback on how I could write my functions more efficient

Tags: javascript, function

Alright, so I'm learning Javascript and I love it.
I wanted to try getting data from an API and display it on my screen and everything works like a charm.

But looking at my code, I see room for improvement.
A lot of the code repeats itself multiple times and I want to avoid that for obvious reasons.

How would you write the code so it became drier?

```
const btcApi = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";
const btc = document.getElementById("btc");

const sekBtn = document.getElementById("sek");
const gbpBtn = document.getElementById("gbp");
const eurBtn = document.getElementById("eur");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getBtcValue);
sekBtn.addEventListener("click", getBtcValue);
gbpBtn.addEventListener("click", getBtcGBP);
eurBtn.addEventListener("click", getBtcEUR);

function getBtcValue() {
  fetch(btcApi)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      btc.innerHTML = "1BTC = " + data.SEK.last + data.SEK.symbol;
    });
}

function getBtcGBP() {
  fetch(btcApi)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      btc.innerHTML = "1BTC = " + data.GBP.symbol + data.GBP.last;
    });
}

function getBtcEUR() {
  fetch(btcApi)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      btc.innerHTML = "1BTC = " + data.EUR.last + data.EUR.symbol;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to pass a parameter indicating the property to access - or retrieve it from the DOM. Figure out a unique selector that can select all 3 buttons, then:

```
const handler = (event) => {
  const type = event.target.id;
  fetch(btcApi)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      btc.textContent = "1BTC = " + data[type].last + data[type].symbol;
    })
    // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part; don't ignore errors
};
// fix below selector as needed
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', handler);
}
button[0].click();
```

Since it looks like the buttons already exist when this script runs, there shouldn't be any need to wait for DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same actions in every function. I would recommend you to use Computed Property Names [Read more about Computed Property Names](https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/):

```
function getBtc(firstParameter, secondParameter) {
  fetch(btcApi)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      btc.innerHTML = "1BTC = " + data.GBP.[firstParameter] + data.GBP.[secondParameter];
    });
}
```

Or use event.target:

```
function getBtc(event, firstParameter, secondParameter) {
let target = event.target;
let targetType = event.target.classList[0]; 
  fetch(btcApi)
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      btc.innerHTML = "1BTC = " + data[targetType][firstParameter] + data[targetType][secondParameter];
    });
}
```

If you want you can use something else (for example data-... attribute) instead of classList[0]

## Advice

Use this when you use DOMContentLoaded event:

```
function work() { /*...*/ }

if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  // Still loads, wait...
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', work);
} else {
  // DOM is ready!
  work();
}
```